# How to place variables inside button target selector

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, selector, target-action

I have a button that I add a target to, the selector contain a variable.
Can I add the variable into the selector without receiving an error?
Thank you in advance.

```
//this cause a selector error when run
self.save.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.saveItems(dataToSave)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: https://nickharris.wordpress.com/2016/03/23/selectors-with-parameters-in-swift-2-2/

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan I understand I can use myViewController.MyMethod(_:) but how do I place the variable I want to use inside of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an additional function to use it as an action `selector` argument

```
func helperFunc() {
    self.saveItems(dataToSave)
}
```

And then add it

```
self.save.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.helperFunc), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```